# javascript function callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm working with angularjs and phonegap and came cross this code that I "know" what it does, but I do not know how how it works. I'm still getting comfortable with advance js concepts so if you could be a little descriptive, I could really appreciate it.

Questions:

1. In the callback registration, I do not see the following variables set anywhere:  arguments(line 5) and fn(line 10). Are they declared in the function prototype?
2. Is the block of code on line 9 and 15 just setting the "this" value so that in the callback the "this" value points to the same object? What do we call this technique of apply the "this" value?

```
    myApp.factory('phonegapReady', function() {
        return function (fn) {
           var queue = [];
           var impl = function () {
               queue.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));    
            };

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                queue.forEach(function (args) {
                    fn.apply(this, args);
                });
               impl = fn;
            }, false);

            return function () {
                 return impl.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) is a variable that is always available inside a function and is an array-like object that contains all the arguments passed to the function. The reason `Array.prototype.slice.call` is being used is because `arguments` isn't an exactly an array (its an object that has sequential numeric keys `0`,`1`, etc.) and that code is one way of turning it into a real JavaScript Array.

`fn` is a parameter passed into the function at line 2 and is available to the inner function at lines 10 and 12 because of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) (the inner function has access to all the variables of its outer function, even after the outer function returns).

As far as the `apply` calls with `this` go, you are correct in that it sets what object the function is being called on and thereby what object `this` would refer to inside those functions.

However, it is important to note that the value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is dynamic and determined at the time a function is executed and not when its declared.  For example, in the `forEach` loop, `this` refers to the global object (which might be intended), and not the object that triggered the `deviceready` event.  In the last line, the value of `this` will depend on how the result of the whole `phonegapReady` callback is called.